# Set NA and "" Cells in R Dataframe to NULL

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a Dataframe in R where certain rows in some of the columns have values that are `NA` or empty strings `""`. I want to convert these to `NULL` values.

So I need any cells in my data frame that are `NA` or `""` to be `NULL`. How can I do this?

When I try:

```
DF[ , DF$Column == NA] <- NULL
```

or

```
DF[ , DF$Column == ""] <- NULL
```

I get the error: `missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames`

If I try:

```
DF[ , is.na(DF$Column)] <- NULL
```

I get the error: `duplicate subscripts for columns`

If I try:

```
is.na(DF$Column) <- NULL
```

or

```
DF[DF == NA] <- NULL
```

I dont get any errors, but nothing changes in my dataframe.

Comment: This is a misuse of a NULL value in R. Vectors (which is essentially a column in a data.frame) cannot contain a mixture of observed values and NULL values. In R, we prefer NA to NULL to represent missing data. NULL values are used to remove elements from columns even entire columns.

Comment: Got it, thanks! So I will eventually be loading this data set into a SQL DB. Will SQL interpret NA as NULL?

Comment: Depends how you do it. If you use `RODBC::sqlSave`, yeah, I'm pretty sure that's how it works.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no NULL value in a vector. NA is the placeholder. If you want to remove the entire column (which is what assigning NULL would do) when its values are all NA then this would succeed:

```
df[ , sapply(df, function(x) all(is.na(x)) ) ] <- NULL
```

If you want to construct an object where you keep only those rows with no NA values:

```
df[ apply(df,1, function(rw) !any(is.na(rw)) ) , ]
```